# How to inser an array value to array in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sql-update

The data column of user table is as follows.

```
data                 | {"user": [["id", true], ["name", true], ["email", true], ["address", true], ["dob", true]], "prime_user": [["id", true], ["name", true], ["email", true], ["address", true], ["dob", true]], "premium_user": [["id", true], ["name", true], ["email", true], ["address", true], ["dob", true]]}
```

Now for this data, I want to add another value `["first_name", true]` next to the id, to each array(user, prime_user, premium_user) of these data. i.e. I want to update the above value as below

```
{
   "user":[
      [
         "id",
         true
      ],
      [
         "first_name",
         true
      ],
      [
         "name",
         true
      ],
      [
         "email",
         true
      ],
      [
         "address",
         true
      ],
      [
         "dob",
         true
      ]
   ],
   "prime_user":[
      [
         "id",
         true
      ],
      [
         "first_name",
         true
      ],
      [
         "name",
         true
      ],
      [
         "email",
         true
      ],
      [
         "address",
         true
      ],
      [
         "dob",
         true
      ]
   ],
   "premium_user":[
      [
         "id",
         true
      ],
      [
         "first_name",
         true
      ],
      [
         "name",
         true
      ],
      [
         "email",
         true
      ],
      [
         "address",
         true
      ],
      [
         "dob",
         true
      ]
   ]
}
```

I have tried something like this, but it is not working. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

```
$data = $user->data;
$inserted = array("first_name", true);
foreach ($data as $d) {
    array_splice($d, 1, 0, $inserted );
}
$user->data = $data;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

array_splice uses the reference but you are using $d which is a local variable for the loop and it doesn't affect the $data variable.

try using `array_splice($data[$key] , ... )` instead , add `$key` in loop like this : `foreach($data as $key => $d)`

Comment: Thanks. It is inserting like this `{"user": [["id", true], "first_name", true, ["name", true] ....}`. How can I enter it like `["first_name", true]`?

Comment: try using `$inserted = array(["first_name", true]);`

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop like this and you will get your result

```
 foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $data[$key] = array_merge(array_slice($value, 0, 1),[$inserted ],array_slice($value, 1));
    }
```

may it helps....